# Pytorch - How to index tensor with different sizes along an axis

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I have a tensor `T` with shape `(8, 8, 4, 4)` and I have 2 vectors, `x` and `y` for indexing the last 2 dimensions of this tensor.

For example:

```
x = tensor([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2])
y = tensor([2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3])
```

I want to set the elements at the indices of the tensor as `-1`. The result is expected to be the same as this for loop but only with pytorch without any loop.

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        T[i, j, :x[i], :y[j]] = -1
```

Can this be done without any loop? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: How big are `T`, `x`, and `y`?

Comment: The first dimension of ```T``` can be up to a million but the second dimension can be as small as 50 or 100. The last 2 dimensions can be at most 50. But I will perform this operation multiple times and I am trying to avoid it taking too much time.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done in an efficient way those patches are non-contiguous and non-homogeneous between batches...

Comment: I thought maybe there is a helper function doing something like this in pytorch or maybe even in numpy, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: NumPy and PyTorch don't work with non-homogeneous operations. You can one-handedly assign `-1` to all `T[i, j, x[i], y[j]]` but doing `T[i, j, :x[i], :y[j]]` is a much more complex operation because the number of components to assign "per `i,j`" varies.